# Java OpenGL: Check collision of 2 Objects with model matrix

Tags: java, opengl, collision-detection

Is it possible to check the collision of 2 Objects by using the model matrix?

I have this 2 Objects:

```
Entity player = new Entity();
player.setObjectModel(this.loader.loadEntity("res/game/meshes/cube2.obj"));
Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();
mat.translate(-2.0f, -11.0f, 0.1f);
mat.scale(4.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
player.setModelMatrix(mat);
```

and

```
Entity ball = new Entity();
ball.setObjectModel(this.loader.loadEntity("res/game/meshes/cube2.obj"));
Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();
mat.translate(1.0f, -9.0f, 0.1f);
mat.scale(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
ball.setModelMatrix(mat);
```

So can I use their model matrix to check a collision or what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

A model matrix is just an operator which describes transformation, so you can't use it to test for collision at all. A model matrix can translate a mesh +10 in the y-axis and scale it by a factor of 100; however, if the mesh itself is, for example, of 0 volume, it won't really scale anything and a collision would never happen regardless. This shows that it's the mesh itself that matters, and a model matrix is just a something you apply to the coordinates of that mesh to orient it correctly in your world space.

What you can do is use the model matrix to transform local hitboxes/spheres/whatevershape for the objects you wish to test, and then you check if these shapes collide.

How you test for collision between 2 shapes is stuff you can find all over the internet. However, if you're going with something other than simple non-rotated bounding boxes or spheres, I'd recommend looking for a helper Physics library. Bullet Physics is a very powerful one which has been ported to java as [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/).